# linphone registration in android

Tags: android, linphone, linphone-sdk

I would like to develop an application using Linphone library.

I have searched some tutorials and examples but in the example in Github it doesn’t explain how exactly to register to a sip server or maybe I didn’t understood these examples ?

I have found this : http://www.linphone.org/docs/liblinphone-javadoc/

But it doesn’t work for me or maybe I have miss something ?

Where can I find some examples with registration to a sip servers / call manager ?

How should I register? Which classes should be used? 
For example :
in linphone application source code there is :

```
accountCreator = LinphoneCoreFactory.instance().createAccountCreator
```

But there isn't any "createAccountCreator" in this class

How can I find any help our examples?

Answer (score 0):

please refer to https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android example.
Basically, you need to set mLc.addAuthInfo and mLc.addProxyConfig with your SIP service credentials and library from example will register in background.